# Structuring transactional data for Sankey Diagram

Tags: r, plyr, sankey-diagram

There are a lot of packages for Sankey diagrams. However, these packages assume the data is already structured. I'm looking at a transaction dataset where I would like to pull out the first sequence of products in a time series. Assume the time series is already ordered.

Here is the dataset:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1546300800, 1546646400, 1547510400, 1547596800, 1546387200, 1546646400, 1546732800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               client = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
               product = c("butter", "cheese", "cheese", "butter", "milk", "garbage bag", "candy"),
               qty = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Here is the desired output:

[image: image1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposal:

```
dt <-structure(list(date = structure(c(1546300800, 1546646400, 1547510400, 1547596800, 1546387200, 1546646400, 1546732800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               client = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                          product = c("butter", "cheese", "cheese", "butter", "milk", "garbage bag", "candy"),
               qty = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(data.table)
library(stringr)
dt <- as.data.table(dt)
dt[, From:=shift(product,type = "lag"), by=client]
dt <- dt[!is.na(From)]

setnames(dt, "product", "To")
dt <- dt[From!=To]
setcolorder(dt, c("client", "From", "To", "qty"))
dt[, comp:=paste0(sort(c(From, To)), collapse = "_"), by=seq_len(nrow(dt))]
dt <- unique(dt, by="comp")

dt[, date:=NULL]
dt[, comp:=NULL]
```

A caveat: why was cheese to cheese deleted? I assumed that you are looking for sequence of different products. If it is for other reasons my code might need some tweaks.

```
#  client        From          To qty       
#      a      butter      cheese   3 
#      b        milk garbage bag   4 
#      b garbage bag       candy   6
```

Comment: Thanks!  Correct looking for sequence of different products which should feed well into the Sankey.

Comment: Looking for unique flows for each client.  In the new example there should be a "butter to cheese" added to client b.  structure(list(date = structure(c(1546300800, 1546646400, 1547510400, 
1547596800, 1546387200, 1546646400, 1546732800, 1546819200, 1546992000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), client = c("a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), product = c("butter", 
"cheese", "cheese", "butter", "milk", "garbage bag", "candy", 
"butter", "cheese"), qty = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: I changed the unique statement to achieve this and added client             dt <- unique(dt, by="comp", by="client")